# Redux-form how find the store?

Tags: react-native, redux-form

I'm new in React native, I would like to use redux-form.

Could you help me ?

I have this error:

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Form(CreateIndicator))."
```

ConfigureStore:

```js
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer
})
const reducer = createStore(rootReducer);
export default reducer;
```

App.tsx (main component):

```js
import configureStore from '../my-bullet-journal/components/utils/configureStore';

export default function App() {
  configureStore;
  ...
}
```

My form component:

```js
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

let CreateIndicator = () => {
   ...
}
CreateIndicator = reduxForm({
    form: 'indicator' //a unique name for this form
})(CreateIndicator);
```

My configuration is it sufficient ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed that part in App.tsx

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../my-bullet-journal/components/utils/configureStore';


export default function App() {
return(
<Provider store={configureStore}>
...
</Provider>
```

Although I suggest better naming for your variables:

in ConfigureStore:

```
const configureStore = createStore(rootReducer);
export default configureStore;
```

As it is your default export the name is really up to you but it would be confusing to call your variable `reducer` inside of configureStore